# How to make a dropdown genre menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[dropdown Genre menu that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb7Qh.png)

As the picture says, I want to make it like that but the twist here is this.

I want to hover at the genres (not the button) to see the movies that are hovered on.

Example: I hovered at adventure so I will immediately see the movies that are an adventure.

I want to make the Genre button itself clickable not hover but the genres (e.g. horror, action) are hover so that If I hover at them, I can immediately see the movies and at the same time clickable so that if I click at that selected genre it will stay on that genre.

This is what I have done. I can only search for movie titles but not the genre itself. So I want to make a dropdown menu for the genre to be able to search for the genre. [This is the work that I want to put the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G93E9.png)

Answer (score 1):

```css
select{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
option{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>All</option>
<option>Action</option>
<option>Adventure</option>
<option>Animation</option>
<option>Biography</option>
<option>Comedy</option>
<option>Crime</option>
<option>Documentary</option>
</select>
```